# When is beneficial to pass function type in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
private fun createData(
index: Int,
address: () -> Address)
```

and here is the method call

`createData(0){Address(...)}`

or I can keep simple and instead I can have

```
private fun createData(
index: Int,
address  -> Address)
```

and I will call just simple way createData(0,Address(...))
I am just wondering in this case is there any benefit to use function type?

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly the benefit of passing a function into `createData` is without knowing what it's supposed to do with it.

Comment: It could be beneficial, when getting the address is resource heavy or time intensive and `createData`  only calls it when it is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you're showing is a function take takes a "factory" as a parameter. If you are only ever going to immediately call the function exactly one time, then there is no reason not to just take the Address parameter directly.

But suppose creating an Address is a CPU intensive process and you might not need it until later, if at all. Then you could hold onto the function and only use it later if it is truly needed.

Or suppose you want to create a bunch of Addresses using some kind of input parameter. Then you might want to take a parameter like `(Int) -> Address` and call it multiple times using different parameters.

Or suppose this function is going to need some number of copies of the Address, and Address doesn't have a copy function. Then you could call the function over and over to get copies.

There are many other uses for higher order functions. I'm just giving a few examples of uses of them for a factory, since that's the kind of example you asked about. But a couple of far more general uses:

- If the function is supposed to do an action to multiple objects, and you want callers to be able to pass what that action is.
- In place of an interface, you can use a function parameter to allow greater flexibility for what is passed to it (a lambda, a defined function, or a SAM interface)